# How do electromagnetic lenses magnify the image?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, lenses, microscopy

In optical microscope both objective and eyepiece are used to magnify the sample image. Magnification is determined by laws of geometrical optics (intersection of optical beams from the same point of the sample)

In electron microscope, electromagnetic lenses are used to magnify the sample image. How do such lenses enable magnification of sample image? Since the way image is formed isn't determined by laws of geometrical optics.